How to figure out the gauge and number of turn to create an electromagnet?
I'm trying to make a simple DC motor (nothing serious), I bought varnished copper wire (0.5 mm/22 AWG but don't mind buying more or different gauge if necessary). I made a simple magnet with 4 or 5 AAA batteries (6 - 7.5V), using the entirety of the copper wire (10 m). I was wondering if their were a formula that I can input data into its variables to trying a figure out which would be the cheapest electromagnet I can make that will fit my DIY DC motor.
Possible variables are: Voltage of the source, diameter of the wire (gauge), length of the wire, number of turns of the wire (maybe also depending of the diameter or shape - circular or flat - of the turns).
Note that I have a multimeter (measuring voltage, resistance, current). But do not own and impedance-meter (if it is ever needed). I also have ferrite magnets for the DC motor (but they won't help figure out my wire concerns if I'm not mistaken).

The mechanical design, especially the magnetic paths is more important than the electromagnetic.

If this is just for a demonstration then  just make many turns, more turns will run slower with more torque.
Fewer turns will run faster and use more current.
20 turns is probably a good starting point.
